# Как обновить поля по правилам в Cassandra?

Tags: база-данных, cassandra

Я создал таблицу в кассандре
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После чего заполнил её некоторыми данными и в конце создал при помощи alter table столбец email.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сейчас я хочу заполнить столбец email значениями в формате имя + . + фамилия + - + группа + @mail.ru

Получилось пока только написать кастомную функцию для вывода подобного.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Данные выводить получается, а как их занести в столбец? Что ни пробовал, везде ошибка.
Ошибки появляются во время выполнения update
В основном SyntaxException: line ... no viable alternative at input
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос что вы пробовали, на чём ошибка выходила. `UPDATE`?